# How to control what image to show when sharing webpage on social media or via mobile devices?

Tags: html, iphone, facebook, bootstrap-4, share

I have an e-commerce website and I want to be able to control what image shows up when the user shares my product description. I have a product description page which displays a gallery of product images and an `aside` element that contains related product sections.

However, when a user shares the page using the iPhone, the device shows 4 images and these images are from the related product. I want the control which image is visible when sharing using iPhone, I want the main image of the product to be visible not the related product images.

Here is the HTML content of the page. The image that I want to show during the share is `https://example.com/sharable-photos/1/141152923/1.jpg`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="twitter:image" property="og:image" content="https://example.com/sharable-photos/1/141152923/1.jpg" />
        <meta name="twitter:image:alt"property="og:image:alt" content="..." />
        <meta name="twitter:image:width" property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
        <meta name="twitter:image:height" property="og:image:height" content="800" />
        <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" content="..." />
    </head>
    <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">

        <div itemprop="primaryImageOfPage" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <meta itemprop="contentUrl" content="https://example.com/sharable-photos/1/141152923/1.jpg" />
            <meta itemprop="caption" content="..." />
            <div itemprop="thumbnail" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <meta itemprop="contentUrl" content="https://example.com/thumbnails/1/141152923/1.jpg" />
                <meta itemprop="caption" content="..." />
            </div>
        </div>

        <header itemprop="hasPart" itemtype="http://www.schema.org/WPHeader" itemscope id="header">...</header>

        <main role="main">

            <!--Product Main Content-->
            <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope itemref="similar_1 similar_2 similar_3 similar_4">

                <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
                <div id="carousel_thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

                    <!--Slides-->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                        <figure class="carousel-item active">
                            <picture>
                                <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="https://example.com/thumbnails/1/141152923/1.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 301px;) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/1.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 768px;) and (max-width: 991px;) 83vw" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/1.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 1200px) 67vw" srcset="https://example.com/sharable-photos/1/141152923/1.jpg">
                                <img src="https://example.com/1/141152923/1.jpg" alt="..." class="image-cover" />
                            </picture>
                        </figure>

                        <figure class="carousel-item ">
                            <picture>
                                <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="https://example.com/thumbnails/1/141152923/2.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 301px;) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/2.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 768px;) and (max-width: 991px;) 83vw" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/2.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 1200px) 67vw" srcset="https://example.com/sharable-photos/1/141152923/2.jpg">
                                <img src="https://example.com/1/141152923/2.jpg" alt="..." class="image-cover" />
                            </picture>
                        </figure>

                        <figure class="carousel-item ">
                            <picture>
                                <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="https://example.com/thumbnails/1/141152923/3.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 301px;) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/3.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 768px;) and (max-width: 991px;) 83vw" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/3.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 1200px) 67vw" srcset="https://example.com/sharable-photos/1/141152923/3.jpg">
                                <img src="https://example.com/1/141152923/3.jpg" alt="..." class="image-cover" />
                            </picture>
                        </figure>

                        <figure class="carousel-item ">
                            <picture>
                                <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="https://example.com/thumbnails/1/141152923/4.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 301px;) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/4.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 768px;) and (max-width: 991px;) 83vw" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/4.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 1200px) 67vw" srcset="https://example.com/sharable-photos/1/141152923/4.jpg">
                                <img src="https://example.com/1/141152923/4.jpg" alt="..." class="image-cover" />
                            </picture>
                        </figure>

                        <figure class="carousel-item ">
                            <picture>
                                <source media="(max-width: 300px)" srcset="https://example.com/thumbnails/1/141152923/5.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 301px;) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/5.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 768px;) and (max-width: 991px;) 83vw" srcset="https://example.com/1/141152923/5.jpg">
                                <source media="(min-width: 1200px) 67vw" srcset="https://example.com/sharable-photos/1/141152923/5.jpg">
                                <img src="https://example.com/1/141152923/5.jpg" alt="..." class="image-cover" />
                            </picture>
                        </figure>

                        <!--Controls-->
                        <div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel_thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel_thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.Controls-->

                    </div>
                    <!--/.Slides-->

                </div>
                <!--./Carousel Wrapper-->
            </article>
            <!--./Product Main Content-->

            <!--Related Products-->
            <aside class="card">
                <div class="card-header text-center text-uppercase">
                    <h2 class="text-info">Related Products</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body row pt-0 pl-3 pr-3">

                    <!--Related Product 1-->
                    <div class="col-12" itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope id="similar_1">
                        <div class="card bg-dark">
                            <picture>
                                <meta itemprop="image" content="https://example.com/primary-thumbnails/1/142262618/primary.jpg" />
                                <img intrinsicsize="250 x 175" loading="lazy" class="card-img-top" src="https://example.com/primary-thumbnails/1/142262618/primary.jpg" alt="..." title="View more info" />
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--./Related Product 1-->

                    <!--Related Product 2-->
                    <div class="col-12" itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope id="similar_2">
                        <div class="card bg-dark">
                            <picture>
                                <meta itemprop="image" content="https://example.com/primary-thumbnails/1/142140140/primary.jpg" />
                                <img intrinsicsize="250 x 175" loading="lazy" class="card-img-top" src="https://example.com/primary-thumbnails/1/142140140/primary.jpg" alt="..." title="View more info" />
                            </picture>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--./Related Product 2-->

                    <!--Related Product 3-->
                    <div class="col-12" itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope id="similar_3">
                        <div class="card bg-dark">
                            <picture>
                                <meta itemprop="image" content="https://example.com/primary-thumbnails/1/142140139/primary.jpg" />
                                <img intrinsicsize="250 x 175" loading="lazy" class="card-img-top" src="https://example.com/primary-thumbnails/1/142140139/primary.jpgg" alt="..." title="View more info" />
                            </picture>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--./Related Product 3-->

                    <!--Related Product 4-->
                    <div class="col-12" itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope id="similar_4">
                        <div class="card bg-dark">
                            <picture>
                                <meta itemprop="image" content="https://example.com/primary-thumbnails/1/142140130/primary.jpg" />
                                <img intrinsicsize="250 x 175" loading="lazy" class="card-img-top" src="https://example.com/primary-thumbnails/1/142140130/primary.jpgg" alt="..." title="View more info" />
                            </picture>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--./Related Product 4-->

                </div>
            </aside>
            <!--./Related Products-->
        </main>

        <footer itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">...</footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

How to control what image to show when sharing webpage on social media or via mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically do that using a server-side programming language like PHP or whichever server-side language you are using for the website